# Microdata for dictionary : can I use yandex

Tags: microdata, google-rich-snippets, vocabulary, yandex

I'm willing to use microdata/microformat/etc. for the part of my website which is an online dictionary. Basically I just want to tag word and definition to help search engines to grab the most important data in every page belonging to the dictionary, and maybe have Google use them as "rich snippets" in results page.

Main problem is it's hard to find dedicated vocabulary for words and definitions (no problem for recipes, movies and hotels though) and I'm not sure if I have to use the "http://schema.org/Article" tree for my lexicographic work. (To my mind, it makes sense to tag something when it's specific enough).

I have found something interesting at Yandex, for words and encyclopedia, I want to ask what to do with. See there :
https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/microdata/what-is-microdata.xml?lang=en
https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/microdata/term-definition-markup.xml

It looks like it is very close to my request. But I'm sorry I dont know what is Yandex... will it work with Google ?
I'm asking here if that page, from Yandex, is a working model, is still on use, what are the pros and cons ? Will Google be able to use the specific vocabulary from Yandex and understand my Yandex-tagged data ? is it worth using that vocabulary for an online dictionary, or is something else I have missed of better use ?

(http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/term-def.xml, which should be the vocabulary url, gives me a 404).

One more question, please : am I allowed to write (duplicate) the most important data in the header, something like (I believe I am, because Google microdata testing tool prooves to be able to extract the data from that code) :

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/term-def.xml">
      <meta itemprop="term" content="My term" />
      <meta itemprop="definition" content="My definition" />
```

Just to mention I was interested, though not happy with these close discussions :

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55073/what-meta-tag-or-structured-data-should-i-use-for-a-dictionary-web-application
- [schema.org and an online dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698336/schema-org-and-an-online-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yandex is Russia's version of Google, and typically they both recognize and honor each other's search engine result implementations.
These articles you are referencing are incredibly outdated; I recommend you seeking out fresher sources, preferably where the term being defined uses the proper HTML element.
[Here's the Yandex URL that is 404ing, the Wayback Machine is your friend!](http://web.archive.org/web/20131221121439/http://webmaster.yandex.ru/vocabularies/term-def.xml)
Back to fresher documentation/resources, in this case the correct element as of 2016-10-05 is the `<dfn>` element. I know you want added semantics, but semantics is the proper place to start, and I'd follow that up by marking the entire dictionary up within a Definition List element, and placing the definition wrapped in the definition element into the `<dt>`, and the definition's of the term in the corresponding `<dd>`s.

I wouldn't waste time trying to find the perfect ontology here; implement [rel="tag" Microformat on all of the definitions], you can always come back and add a more desired one.
[I've written a blog post about this](http://bowdenweb.com/wp/2011/07/semantic-glossary-in-html5.html), but a much more valuable resource is [HTML5 Doctor's Glossary impementation](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/), More importantly, view source - view-source:http://html5doctor.com/element-index/ (why stackoverflow doesn't recognize 'view-source' schema is beyond me)

### More References/Resources:

[Microformats Definition Examples has some very interesting ideas/code snippets](http://microformats.org/wiki/definition-examples)
[Utilizing the Underused by Semantically Awesome Definition List - Written Prior to HTML5's Redefinition of `<dl>` but Relevant](https://css-tricks.com/utilizing-the-underused-but-semantically-awesome-definition-list/)

Comment: Well, if quoted Yandex vocabulary for microdata is outdated, I'm going to look for something else. Good to know.